# How to define a recursive function in Excel or how to define how long a field takes to change (Distance measured by Value_Column_X - Value_Column_Y)

Tags: excel, recursion, time-series

The title of this question is assuming a way to solve it but what I need is the most simple way to get in Excel the following: -by most simple I mean in the terms of tools used; for example using VB is less simple that using Formulas and Pivot tables; the reason of the restriction is that my skills in Excel do not include VB or any other generic language.

There is a defects table with a daily sanpshot of the current testing status and I want to know how many days one defect in a given status X has been in this status.

For example the table could have records like:

| ID | Date | Status | Calculated_Field_Consecutive_Days_In_Same_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 1/Feb | Open | 1 |
| 23 | 2/Feb | Open | 2 |
| 23 | 3/Feb | Ready_For_Testing | 1 |
| 23 | 4/Feb | Ready_For_Testing | 2 |
| 23 | 5/Feb | Ready_For_Testing | 3 |
| 23 | 6/Feb | Open | 1 |
| 23 | 7/Feb | Ready_For_Testing | 1 |
| 23 | 8/Feb | Closed | 1 |

---

The following is not necessary to answer the question but nice if you have a useful comment on this.

Hint of how far I get: Using xloopup and simple formulas I can create a column that for each record tells me if the Status fields is new. But when I use this column to build a recursive function over the column itself where the base case is 1 and the recursive case is Value_of_Column for Predecesor_Record it does not work as Excel behaves as it is calculating the full column like an atomic operation instead of calculating one record after the other

---

Change Log:

- On 21/2 Feb I change my table sample to show one scenario that I have not mentioned before and it is not covered by the first solution provided: The satus field can have a sequence like this one over time A,B,C,C,B,C and counter should be reset each time there is a change of value. In the case motivating this question it means that a defect can be Ready_for_Testing for 3 days but then the bug would be tested and if bug is still there it means the defect goes back to Open and eventually to Ready_for_Testing again with a counter of 1 day old.

Answer (score 0):

*assuming status for an ID is logged once a day, and the dates are sorted ascending*
Try:

```
D2: =COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$C$2:C2,C2)
```

and fill down.

[image]

Comment: This solution solves the question as I phrased in my original post but now (1 day later) I have edited the original post and highighted one detail that is important to cover that is not solved by this approach. Notice that I have edited the sample table.

Comment: @MartiSanchez How have you tried to modify what I show to meet your real requirements? *I suppose this is one of the reasons that a policy of this forum is that you show your own work before asking for help. It often clarifies the problem that you really want to have answered*.  With this added degree of complexity, I would suggest you develop a VBA solution.

Comment: Regarding explaining how I tried to solve it : I did point out that when you try to define the value of one column on itself the calculation engine seems to be using a copy of the full column before updates are started. Therefore it did not seem a promising path to follow and did not provide details. The take away is one: the calculation was atomic at the level of the column and not atomic at the level of the rows; if there is any knowledge here on the way the excel engine resolve formulas which auto refence the same column it will be useful.

Comment: @ronsenfeld Regarding if your solution can be modified: I think your method cannot be extended to make it work (I know you usually cannot prove there is not a solution…). Your method is not sensitive to how records are sorted by the Status field: it means that depending how the records are sorted by the Status field you get one result or another. Your method relies on sorting by dates which makes sense in the problem but would rely also on the sorting of the status which cannot be assumed. I willl try VBA as you suggest.

Comment: @MartiSanchez Yes, I think `VBA`, or possibly `Power Query`, would provide a more easily understood and maintainable solution